# How to get TouchEvent on Windows desktop for OpenFL app?

Tags: windows, touch, haxe, openfl, nme

I'm on a touch enabled Windows machine compiling [OpenFL](http://www.openfl.org/). I'm compiling to the Windows/C++ target using OpenFL and Haxe 3.

I cannot get touch events to work. Here's where I'm adding them:

```
private function onAdded(e:Event):Void 
{       
    stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resize);

    resize(null);

    init(); 

    addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

    addEventListener( TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin );
    stage.addEventListener( TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, onTouchMove );
    stage.addEventListener( TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd );

}
```

My `enterFrame()` is getting invoked just fine. No touch (or using mouse) triggers the handlers. Is this a Windows desktop limitation? Would this work once I put on iOS and Android? Why not? Is this a NME/OpenFL bug?

Comment: Also, MouseEvent works fine when using the mouse, and also not mistakenly triggered by touching.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mouse in place of touch on windows for now with the 1.1 update, until full support for multitouch is implemented. Works fine for iOS and Android etc.

[singmajesty on the forum](http://www.openfl.org/index.php?cID=14594&ccm_paging_p=1&time=1383778229#msg14691)

Try it the other way, use a MouseEvent to handle both mouse and touch input on a desktop.

We just (in OpenFL 1.1, released this week) migrated to SDL2 for the backend for Windows. This actually has support for real touch events, so in the future I expect to see multi-touch support for the desktop. It just was not that long ago that this was only a thing for mobile devices smiling

So if you don't need to track individual touch points separately, mouse events should do it for you today. Otherwise, we're positioned now to be able to wire support for this in the not-too-distant future smiling